# Mutiseat with 14.04 using Intel onboard and Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, intel, multiseat

I try to set up a multiseat system on Kubuntu 14.04. The system has an Intel on-board GPU and a PCIe Nvida GPU. I have added the Mutiseat PPA.The following config files did more or less work in Kubuntu 13.10 but now on a freshly installed 14.04 both screens stay dark. I need help to find out what is wrong with my setup. Can anyone help, please?
Does 14.04 already provide multiseat capabilities?

seat0:

```
    Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "seat0"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    #        InputDevice "kbd_0"
    #        InputDevice "mouse_0"
    #    Option      "AutoEnableDevices"     "off"
    #    Option      "AutoAddDevices"        "off"
    #    Option      "AllowEmptyInput"       "on" 
    EndSection

    Section "Module"
        Load           "glx"
    EndSection

    Section "ServerFlags"
             Option         "Xinerama" "0"
            #To avoid problems on the X Server initalization caused by the not recognizing of the mouse
             Option          "AllowMouseOpenFail"     "yes"
            #Disable VT Switching
            #Option        "DontVTSwitch" "True"
    #        Option         "DontVTSwitch" "yes"
            #This disallows the use of the Ctrl+Alt+Backspace sequence
    #        Option         "DontZap"       "yes"
    #        Option         "AllowEmptyInput" "true"
    EndSection  


    Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        #Option         "TwinView" "1"
        #Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
        #Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP-2: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
        SubSection "Display"
            Depth     24
        EndSubSection
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Card0"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BoardName      "GeForce GTX 670"
        BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
        Option         "ProbeAllGpus"        "false"
        Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "Monitor0"
        VendorName     "Unknown"
        ModelName      "HannStar Display Corp Hanns.G Hi221"
        HorizSync      24.0 - 94.0
        VertRefresh    56.0 - 76.0
        Option         "DPMS"
    EndSection

    Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "ignore_other_seats"
        Option          "Ignore" "yes"
    EndSection

    Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "use_seat_devices"
        MatchTag        "input_seat0"
        Option          "Ignore" "no"
    EndSection
```

seat1:

```
    Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "seat1"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    #   InputDevice    "mouse_1" 
    #   InputDevice    "kbd_1" 
    #   Option      "AutoEnableDevices"     "off"
    #        Option      "AutoAddDevices"        "off"  
    #        Option      "AllowEmptyInput"       "on"
            Option          "Xinerama" "off"
    EndSection

    Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     1
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     4
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     8
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     15
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     16
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     24
        EndSubSection
    EndSection



    Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
        Option      "NoLogo" "True"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
    EndSection

    Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "ignore_other_seats"
        Option          "Ignore" "yes"
    EndSection

    Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "use_seat_devices"
        MatchTag        "input_seat1"
        Option          "Ignore" "no"
    EndSection
```

lightdm.conf:

```
    [LightDM]
    seats=Seat:0 Seat:1

    [Seat:0]
    xserver-command=/usr/bin/X -config xorg_nvidia.conf -isolateDevice PCI:1:0:0 :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -sharevts -keeptty #
    autologin-user=demo0
    autologin-user-timeout=5

    [Seat:1]
    xserver-command=/usr/bin/X -config xorg_intel.conf -isolateDevice PCI:0:2:0 :1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp vt7 -sharevts -keeptty #
    autologin-user=demo1
    autologin-user-timeout=5

    [SeatDefaults]
    user-session=kubuntu
    greeter-session=lightdm-kde-greeter
    greeter-show-manual-login=true
    allow-guest=false
    exit-on-failure=true
```

99-seat.rules

```
    # Initially all Input-Devices are allocated to Seat:0
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_default"

    # Seat 0 uses USB-Ports 2 and 3, Seat 1 uses 1 and 4:
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*/usb1/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*/usb2/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*/usb3/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*/usb4/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat1"

    # Seperate sound cards
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*/sound/card0/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*/sound/card1/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat1"

    # Input-Devices for Seat:1 are connected at USB bus 1
    #SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*/usb1/*", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat1"
    #SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/*", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat1"
    #SUBSYSTEM=="input", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/video4linux/video0", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="input_seat1"
    #SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/*, ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat1"
```

Comment: Assuming that config worked in 13.10, check your logs for errors. If nothing else, I would get it working with each seat on it's own first, then multiseat, debug one video card at a time, and then if that works, the multiseat config.

Comment: Just a thought, I hope you got things to work since then, but it looks like you give both seats the same TTY (vt7), is that really legal/possible? Also I think that X11 moved to vt8 because something else uses vt7 on boot...